# Why am I getting a "Too many DML statements: 1" in a non-cacheable Apex method?

Tags: apex, dml

I have this Apex method in a controller class:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void deleteTagAssignment(Id loanId, String name) {
    TagAssignment__c assignment = [
        SELECT Id
        FROM TagAssignment__c
        WHERE Loan__c = :loanId
        AND   Tag__r.Name = :name
    ];
    delete assignment;
}
```

I originally got the error because I was trying to cache the results, but no longer am. A quick Google search solved that. But I removed it and am still getting the error. Why else could that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default mode for caching is enabled for recent API versions. You must specifically disable it via `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)`.